# Proof regarding extreme point of a convex set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I´m having trouble proving the following:

> Let $C\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove $x \in C$ is an extreme point of $C$ if and only if $C\setminus {x}$ is convex.

For the sufficiency, I figured if $x$ is an extreme point then the result follows since any other point can be expressed as a convex combination.
The necessity part is where I´m stuck at, since I´m supposed to do it by contradiction.

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is extreme and $C \setminus \{x\}$ is not convex. In particular, there are $a,b$ and $t \in (0,1)$ such that $a,b \in C$ but $tb+(1-t)a \notin C$. Then we must have $x=tb+(1-t)a$ but this contradicts $x$ being extreme.
Hence $C \setminus \{x\}$ is convex.

If $ x$ is not extreme, then there are $a,b$ different from $x$ and $t \in (0,1)$ such that $x=tb+(1-t)a$. Hence $C \setminus \{x\}$ is not convex.